# Create "organization" automatically when user signs up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication with two custom fields added = `:organization_id` and `:username`. I also generated a scaffold for the Organization which simply consists of Name.

Currently when users sign up they can type in an Organization ID (integer) and a username (string).

Users `belong_to` organizations, and organizations `has_many` users.

Here's what my models look like (I left everything else untouched except for the files inside app/views/devise/registrations to add organization_id and username):

***#user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :organization_id, :username

end
```

***#organization.rb***

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

What I would like is for an organization to be automatically created when a user signs up without the user having to specify the organization_id.

Also, ideally the `@organization.name` would be exactly the same as `:username`

How would I go about doing this?

I've seen the Railscast on [nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast) but he's creating a question inside the survey form, and questions belong to a survey. I need to do it the other way around (create an organization inside the user form, where users belong to a survey.)

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_organization

  private
  def create_organization
    self.organization = Organization.create :name => self.username
  end
end
```

The `create_organization` method will be executed right before the sql query which creates the user. It'll create a new organization and assign it to the user.

Comment: Whoah, awesome, that worked!!! You have no idea how stoked I am to see this. Is there any way to make it so that :username = @organization.name?

Comment: Hmm unfortunately, that doesn't work -- the organization name is still showing up blank when I sign up for a new account.. Thanks anyway! Let's see if I can try to figure this out.

Comment: I looked at the server logs. The glaring thing that stands out to me is `AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "organizations" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, '2011-12-15 15:24:07.419868', '2011-12-15 15:24:07.419868')` the name is basically not getting passed.

Comment: This is probably a problem of attr_accessible. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

Comment: I got it to work!!! I made a stupid mistake -- I put the `def create_organization` section on top of the user model. I just moved it to the bottom and everything's working fine and dandy now. Thanks again for your help you have no idea how much I appreciate it!